# Usage of "mucking out"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

According to the Oxford dictionary, "mucking out" is defined as:

> "The action of cleaning a stable, etc., by removing dung, soiled straw, and the like".

I work in construction and often see the term "mucking out" when people refer to 'removing the excavation spoil out of the site'.

Is this a valid usage of the term, if not, what term would you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Muck* in the construction trades refers to waste in general, usually in bulk form. A representative use from a company's website:

> The Danjo's Skip Hire grab truck service covers Croydon, Sutton & Kingston, providing a *muck away* service, removing all rubbish & construction waste

It also refers to mining waste in the form of loose rock.

*Muck **away*** is a common use.

*Muck **out*** as a phrasal verb in construction seems vanishingly rare in writing. Attempts to track down this usage are more likely to turn up quotes like *solutions for conveying muck out of tunnels.* (i.e. *muck* as a noun).

However there are quotes like:

> If successful we will muck out and pour. If unsuccessful we will get divers, muck out, and pour.

From *Bridging the Imjin: Construction of Libby and Teal Bridges during the Korean War (October 1952-July 1953)* (from an [appendix that's a log from 1953](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=2wrpgeX2TsUC&pg=PA126&lpg=PA126&dq=%22muck+out%22+divers&source=bl&ots=Z-e_qauFwf&sig=ZvYHLHcpE9j3nu52pBriSx0qfyY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjEuPWEpvXYAhUI56QKHWdEDK8Q6AEILTAC#v=onepage&q=%22muck%20out%22%20divers&f=false)). This is an American use (84th Engineer Battalion officers), unlike my other hits which were British. So the phrasal verb has some history. It's not common though.

Answer (score 0):

That is an example of how languages evolve. There was no word that means exactly what the speaker needs, remove rubbish from a construction site, so they chose the word which has the closest meaning, mucking out = removing waste from a stable.